# Computop Module - in DB eav_attribute & sales_order_status remains after uninstall - how to remove?

Tags: module, attributes, ce-1.8.1.0, customer-address

I have found that under the `admin/customer/edit -> Address` the bottom field is called `computop_checked_address_hash` and is required.

However, the Module - [Official Computop Payment Module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/official-computop-payment-module.html) - is not installed, but it must have been at some point in the past before I had to manage the store.

I've tried to reinstall and deinstall the module, but the field remains. I've not found any occurrences of `computop´ in the files (using a grep search), but in the db it is in two tables:

- `eav_attribute` - 2 fields - computop_risk_check & computop_checked_address_hash
- `sales_order_status` - 3 fields - ready_computop_capture, waiting_auth_computop_note & waiting_capture_computop_note

How can I get rid of this? Is it safe to remove without breaking the store?

I'm running Magento CE 1.8.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it safer to simply mark the is_required = 0, or set the default value to 0 in the eav_attributes field to stop the computop_checked_address_hash field preventing orders?

Comment: Upon further investigation, this seems to be a remnant from an older version of this module. Readin the changelog, it seems that the Version 2.1.0.38544 from the 
12.06.2013 actually states 'address check removed ' - http://dotsource.de/download/changelog_computop_module_2110243616.pdf

Comment: I've now tried to install and de-install the Module Version prior to it having the address check removed - Release 2.0.1. This also did not remove the field from the customers address.

Comment: I've downloaded the module from here: http://freegento.com/magento-extensions/Official_Computop_Payment_Module-2.0.1.36066.tgz and checked the .sql files. In the mysql4-upgrade-1.4.1.1.8-1.4.1.1.9.php it declares: 

'$this->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute(
    'order_address',
    'paymentoperator_checked_address_hash',
    array('type' => 'varchar')
);

$this->endSetup();'

Answer (score 1):

When removing custom modules, Magento does not remove the attributes and config setup by these modules itself. You have to do this yourself. I would suggest you setup a custom module which has a Magento SQL setup script that simply uses the remove attribute code.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->removeAttribute('customer','computop_checked_address_hash');
$installer->endSetup();
```